# How can I chat with multiple users in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I am creating a chat app with authentication. And I implemented it with socketio and for authentication jwt and cookies. I have also attached it to the database and everything is going good.But chatting with multiple people is not working.

Code when user clicks on the user whom he/she wants to chat with

```
async function chattingWith(elem) {
try {
    remove();
    let message = chatInput.value
    elem.classList.add("chatting");
    selectedUser();
    let sender = await getUserHandler();
    console.log(sender);
    console.log(userSelected)
    let id;
    chatID = makeid(20)
    populateChats(message);
    // console.log(obj);
    sender.contacts.forEach((element) => {
        if (!element.chatID) {
            let obj = { chatID, toUser: userSelected, sender: sender._id };
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/setChatID", {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(obj),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(res => {
                return res.json();
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
    })

    sender.contacts.forEach((element) => {
        if (userSelected == element.contactID) {
            console.log(true);
            if (element.chatID) {
                id = element.chatID

                console.log('chatID', id);
                // socket.emit("join chat", id);

            }
        }
    })
    checkAuth();
    socket.emit("join chat", id);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

}

Here getUser is loggedin user information.

I have a key in database chatID both in contacts of receiver and sender from which I am creating socket room when chat is clicked but when I chat with two different accounts it works fine but when I click on other user from one of the side(like chatting with 3rd user) it doesnt work and when I click again on the user that I am chatting previously it doesnt work now too.
Here's the database[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple users chat together at the same time you will need to create rooms that users can join. It is pretty easy to create rooms from which you will send the message to all the joined users and all joined will receive it as long as they are joined in the same room. To store the chat you would have to use the database to store it.

> [Rooms](https://socket.io/docs/v3/rooms/)

Comment: I have implemented join room, justed wanted to know how to retain the old room as well as create a new one too. Because when I chat with one person its good as I switches to the third user it does'nt work.
PS : I am not implementing group chat!

Comment: As I mentioned in this case if you want to have the history of the chat you will have to store it based on some id so that after you switch and go back it will load the old messages as well.

Comment: Fetching the messages from the database isn't the problem I had done it, the messages are showing properly according to the user I click but when I click on from user1 to user2 all things fall down and doesn't work.

Example :
Let's say we have three user 
user1
user2
user3
user1 has one contact which is user2

comment 1/2

Comment: case 1 : so when i open three browser tabs and opens all the three account separately and when from user1 account I click  user2 and from user2 I click user1. So in this case all things works perfectly.
case 2: But now since user 2 has two connected people and I want to chat with user3 so when I click on user3 from user2's account and from user3 i click on user2 account , nothing works and when I get back to the case 1 where user1 and 2 are chatting now that doesnt work after this and when I reload the page and follow the case1 so the case1 works.
I hope you got it
comment 2/2